# Exchange data between Android and Windows - what communication solution to use?

Tags: java, c#, android, windows, communication

I am extending custom written windows based server (c#). Currently server provides two commnication interfaces (SignalR based, and simplified TCP protocol based). Both interfaces work well with windows clients which i also wrote.

There is a new requirement that server should communicate with native Android (java) client. Communication should be bi-directional:
-> server should be able to push data to client
-> client should be able to push data to sever

Can you recommend any usefull communication solution?

It Man.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered JSON over HTTP2?

In HTTP2 you can do a server push which allows bi-directional communication. That being said, often bi-direction communication between a client and server like this is implemented with a polling model.

Another option might be GRPC which allows streaming connections on top of http2. It often uses proto as the serialization format but doesn't have to.

Those two might be worth checking out.

Comment: What is state of http2? I'm not familiar with this protocol - is it well supported on windows / android devices?

Comment: It came out in 2015 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) and it is supported in most languages. You might have a problem if you are using an old version of either csharp or android but I would expect that modern versions fully support it. That being said, I don't know specifically for csharp as I am not an expert.

Comment: Sounds interesting, have to read more about this one. Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: Well i cannot find any 'official' implmentation for dotnet.